# Endless redirect loop in IE when throwing AuthenticationException in Kerberos

Tags: grails, spring-security

In our project we use Spring Security to provide two ways of authentication. The first one is a form-based login using LDAP and the second one is SSO using Kerberos. Both types share common functionality. Kerberos basically gives us the principal which we then use to query an Active Directory using LDAP to retrieve certain data (departments, email address, etc.). For the form-based login, we take the user-provided login/password, validate it against the Active Directory using LDAP and retrieve some information.

In both approaches, we use a (the same) custom `UserDetailsContextMapper` that is responsible for mapping LDAP info to an internal user object.

In the implemented `mapUserFromContext` method we also perform some other validation, e.g. we check if our app-internal user object that is connected to the incoming LDAP user is inactive. In such a case we would throw an `AuthenticationException` instead of returning a `UserDetails` model.

If the authentication fails, the form login page should be displayed with an error message.

Now the problem is, whenever such an exception is thrown in a Kerberos environment using Internet Explorer 8/9/10, it causes a redirect loop. This seems to be related to the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` we injected into the `SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter` bean. The `SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter` bean will try to authenticate, we throw our `AuthenticationException`, it will run into a catch block and processes the failure handler by redirecting to the form login page.

Firefox does not end up in a redirect loop. It displays the login page with an error message.

Also, using a direct link to the form login page in IE will bypass Kerberos and properly redisplay the login page with an error message in case we throw our exception.

Kerberos and SSO work fine. It is just our thrown `AuthenticationException` in combination with Kerberos which is causing the problem.

There is no HTTP/HTTPS switching involved. We always use HTTP in the test environment.

Questions would be:

- Are there any obvious mistakes we make when configuring our process?
- Is the `UserDetailsContextMapper` the best place to perform our custom validations? Are we allowed to throw an `AuthenticationException` there?
- Is there a known limitation with IE and Kerberos which will prevent this from ever working?

Our test environment:

- Grails 2.2.5 application with Spring Security Core/LDAP/Web 3.0.7 and spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.M2
- Grails plugins used for security: spring-security-core:1.2.7.3, spring-security-ldap:1.0.6, spring-security-kerberos:0.1
- Windows 2003 R2 server VM (domain controller)
- Tomcat 7.0.22 running with JDK 1.6.0_27-b07 (on the domain controller)
- Kerberos clients are Windows7 VMs joined to the domain with Internet Explorer 8/9/10

The whole Spring Security related configuration is quite extensive so I'll keep it to a minimum for now and just list the pieces I think are important to the question.

Bean configuration in resources.groovy:

```
    ldapUserDetailsMapper(CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper) {
        grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
    }

    kerberosUserSearch(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch,
        application.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base,
        application.config.grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.filterKerberos,
        ref('contextSource')) {
    }

    kerberosUserDetailsService(LdapUserDetailsService, ref('kerberosUserSearch'), ref('ldapAuthoritiesPopulator')) {
        userDetailsMapper = ref('ldapUserDetailsMapper')
    }

    kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider) {
        userDetailsService = ref('kerberosUserDetailsService')
        ticketValidator = ref('kerberosTicketValidator')
    }

    authenticationFailureHandler(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        defaultFailureUrl = '/login/authfail?login_error=1'
    }

    spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter) {
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
        failureHandler = ref('authenticationFailureHandler')
    }
```

Spring Security related configuration defines certain properties (I omitted the irrelevant ones):

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.derefLink = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = false
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
                '/login/**':     ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/logout/**':    ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
                '/**':           ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']
]
```

The requests that can be observed by using Fiddler are:

- Request to application root (me opening the app in the browser) with a 401 response (WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate).
- Request to application root (Authorization: Negotiate ....) with a 302 response with location header to the authfail page and a strange body that starts with b9, then HTML markup with "Redirecting to..." link and it finishes with a 0. This 302 response is related to the AuthenticationException we throw.
- Request to failure URL /app/login/authfail?login_error=1 and a 302 response (loop starts here and repeats itself)

I can provide more details if needed. Any help and comments are much appreciated.

Spring security debug logging:

```
2014-09-01 08:37:54,884 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/index.gsp'; to: '/index.gsp'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,884 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Candidate is: '/index.gsp'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No HttpSession currently exists
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa3d44: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.0.126; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /index.gsp; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
2014-09-01 08:37:54,900 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa3d44: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.0.126; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache  - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://vs-vm-dev2003:8080/app/]
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Calling Authentication entry point.
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG web.SpnegoEntryPoint  - Sending back Negotiate Header for request: http://vs-vm-dev2003:8080/app/
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
2014-09-01 08:37:54,931 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/index.gsp'; to: '/index.gsp'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Candidate is: '/index.gsp'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@18a92eb. A new one will be created.
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /index.gsp at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:54,993 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Received Negotiate Header for request http://vs-vm-dev2003:8080/app/: Negotiate <omitted>
2014-09-01 08:37:55,009 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider
2014-09-01 08:37:55,009 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider  - Try to validate Kerberos Token
Found key for HTTP/vs-vm-dev2003@DOMAIN.LOCAL(23)
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Using builtin default etypes for permitted_enctypes
default etypes for permitted_enctypes: 3 1 23 16 17 18.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
replay cache for TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL is null.
object 0: 1409575075000/30
object 0: 1409575075000/30
>>> KrbApReq: authenticate succeed.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>>Delegated Creds have pname=TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL sname=krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL authtime=null starttime=20140901123744Z endtime=20140901223743ZrenewTill=20140908123743Z
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 207387731
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 159224545
2014-09-01 08:37:55,212 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider  - Succesfully validated TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL
2014-09-01 08:37:55,212 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch  - Searching for user 'TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL', with user search [ searchFilter: 'mail={0}', searchBase: 'DC=company,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2014-09-01 08:37:55,603 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=company,dc=com', filter = 'mail={0}'
2014-09-01 08:37:55,618 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Found DN: cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:55,634 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Getting authorities for user cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:55,634 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Searching for roles for user 'TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL', DN = 'cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com', with filter member={0} in search base 'OU=Groups,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com'
2014-09-01 08:37:55,634 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Using filter: member=cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:55,665 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Roles from search: []
2014-09-01 08:37:55,665 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper  - Mapping user details from context with DN: cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:56,103 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] ERROR security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper  - The user TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL does not have a corresponding SysX login configured.
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] WARN  web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate <omitted>
com.company.app.security.ex.NoCorrespondingSysXLoginAuthenticationException: 
    at com.company.app.security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper$_mapUserFromContext_closure5.doCall(CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy:73)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:687)
    at com.company.app.security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler  - Redirecting to /login/authfail?login_error=1
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to '/app/login/authfail?login_error=1'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-5] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-09-01 08:37:56,571 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/login/authfail'; to: '/login/authfail'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - Candidate is: '/login/authfail'; pattern is /**; matched=true
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@18a92eb. A new one will be created.
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Received Negotiate Header for request http://vs-vm-dev2003:8080/app/login/authfail: Negotiate <omitted>
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider  - Try to validate Kerberos Token
Found key for HTTP/vs-vm-dev2003@DOMAIN.LOCAL(23)
Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Using builtin default etypes for permitted_enctypes
default etypes for permitted_enctypes: 3 1 23 16 17 18.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
object 0: 1409575076000/31
object 1: 1409575075000/30
object 0: 1409575076000/31
object 1: 1409575075000/30
replay cache found.
>>> KrbApReq: authenticate succeed.
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
>>>Delegated Creds have pname=TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL sname=krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL authtime=null starttime=20140901123744Z endtime=20140901223743ZrenewTill=20140908123743Z
Krb5Context setting peerSeqNumber to: 255994332
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 867958603
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider  - Succesfully validated TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch  - Searching for user 'TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL', with user search [ searchFilter: 'mail={0}', searchBase: 'DC=company,DC=com', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Searching for entry under DN '', base = 'dc=company,dc=com', filter = 'mail={0}'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,587 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Found DN: cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:56,603 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Getting authorities for user cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:56,603 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Searching for roles for user 'TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL', DN = 'cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com', with filter member={0} in search base 'OU=Groups,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,603 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate  - Using filter: member=cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:56,618 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator  - Roles from search: []
2014-09-01 08:37:56,618 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper  - Mapping user details from context with DN: cn=TESTER,ou=Users,ou=Users,dc=company,dc=com
2014-09-01 08:37:56,790 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] ERROR security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper  - The user TESTER@DOMAIN.LOCAL does not have a corresponding SysX login configured.
2014-09-01 08:37:56,868 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] WARN  web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Negotiate Header was invalid: Negotiate <omitted>
com.company.app.security.ex.NoCorrespondingSysXLoginAuthenticationException: 
    at com.company.app.security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper$_mapUserFromContext_closure5.doCall(CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy:73)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:687)
    at com.company.app.security.CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(CustomLdapUserDetailsContextMapper.groovy:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-01 08:37:56,868 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler  - Redirecting to /login/authfail?login_error=1
2014-09-01 08:37:56,868 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to '/app/login/authfail?login_error=1'
2014-09-01 08:37:56,868 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
2014-09-01 08:37:56,868 [http-apr-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: What does the authfail action do in the controller? Does it attempt to redirect to yet another URL?

Comment: @rmlan In fact, it does. authfail extracts the exception from the session and creates an error message. It puts the error message into flash and redirect to the auth action in the same controller. Seems to be the standard Grails way of doing it. We added some debug logging to it and it seems those methods are never really called in the redirect loop.

Comment: Have you turned on Spring Security debug logging? This will show you the various URLs it is matching and the filters that it is running against. This may give you a clue as to why the user is being redirected to a protected page. The key here would be to make sure that the user has the Anonymous token you would expect him/her to.

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with LDAP, or Kerberos. It's just misconfigured navigation.

Comment: @rmlan I have added the debug log to the question (with minor edits to protect the innocent). I appreciate you looking into this. If you spot any problems, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried setting `/login/**` to `['permitAll']` instead of anonymous?

Comment: @rmlan Yes I tried this and got the same results (redirect loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When authentication exception is thrown it causes a redirect due to this configuration:

```
authenticationFailureHandler(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
    defaultFailureUrl = '/login/authfail?login_error=1'
}
```

For some reason, IE keeps sending the `Negotiate` header in each request, thereby triggering the processing in the `SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter` which in turn tries to load user details with the custom `UserDetailsContextMapper` which throws the authentication exception. This causes the endless redirect loop.

A workaround is to bypass the `SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter` for the login/logout pages so that the `Negotiate` header is ignored although present.

The following Spring Security configuration does the trick:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/login/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter',
    '/logout/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```